# Webpack - CSS Loader disable bundling images but not fonts

Tags: webpack

I followed this guide to add bundling fonts to my project, but doing 
`background-image: url('anything.png')` results in webpack(v4) telling me that I need an appropriate loader for `.png` files. Can I somehow disable bundling images without ruining the possibility of bundling fonts?

My solution to this was to add an argument to the `css-loader`,

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: ['css-loader?url=false', 'sass-loader']
    })
},
```

But this obviously messed with

```
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'fonts/'
                }
            }]
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by installing `ignore-loader` and adding the rule

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
    use: 'ignore-loader' 
}
```